# MYSQL in Flutter

Tags: mysql, json, listview, flutter, dart

I have created a database on MYSQL server, now i want to read all data present in table and disolay it in Listview in Flutter, now I am able to raed all data and displayed it on console but in not able to parse that data into Listview.
[image: Data from table.]

```
Future<List<ItemCategory>> getCategory() async {
try {
  http.Response response = await http.post(
      "https://***************.000webhostapp.com/*************.php",
  );
  print('getCategory Response: ${response.body}');
  if (response.body != null) {
    List<ItemCategory> list = parseResponse(response.body);
    return list;
  } else {
    return List<ItemCategory>();
  }
} catch (e) {
  return List<ItemCategory>(); // return an empty list on exception/error
}
  }

  List<ItemCategory> parseResponse(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<ItemCategory>((json) => ItemCategory.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

here is flutter code i am tryying.

and here is the Category class

```
class ItemCategory{
  int catID;
  String catName, catDesc;
  bool matched = false;

  ItemCategory({this.catID, this.catName, this.catDesc});



   factory ItemCategory.fromJson(Map <String, dynamic> json){
     return ItemCategory(
       catID: json['cat_id'] as int,
       catName: json['cat_name'] as String,
       catDesc: json['cat_desc'] as String
     );
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the API response?

Answer (score 0):

So, this website can help you a lot [Json to Dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/). You need to create a listview build.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 2,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    return list[i]
      ? ListTile(
          var item = list[i];
          title: Text(item.title),
        )
      : Container();
   },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can check `response.statusCode` and parse with `itemCategoryFromJson` and display with `FutureBuilder`

```
String jsonString = '''
      [{"cat_id":"2","cat_name":"PAKISTANI","cat_desc":""},{"cat_id":"3","cat_name":"INDIAN","cat_desc":""},{"cat_id":"4","cat_name":"abc","cat_desc":""},{"cat_id":"5","cat_name":"def","cat_desc":""},{"cat_id":"6","cat_name":"hi","cat_desc":""}]
      ''';
http.Response response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);
print('getCategory Response: ${response.body}');
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return itemCategoryFromJson(response.body);
  ...
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

List<ItemCategory> itemCategoryFromJson(String str) => List<ItemCategory>.from(
    json.decode(str).map((x) => ItemCategory.fromJson(x)));

String itemCategoryToJson(List<ItemCategory> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class ItemCategory {
  String catId;
  String catName;
  String catDesc;

  ItemCategory({
    this.catId,
    this.catName,
    this.catDesc,
  });

  factory ItemCategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ItemCategory(
        catId: json["cat_id"],
        catName: json["cat_name"],
        catDesc: json["cat_desc"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "cat_id": catId,
        "cat_name": catName,
        "cat_desc": catDesc,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<ItemCategory>> _future;

  Future<List<ItemCategory>> getCategory() async {
    try {
      //http.Response response = await http.post(
      // "https://***************.000webhostapp.com/*************.php",
      // );

      String jsonString = '''
      [{"cat_id":"2","cat_name":"PAKISTANI","cat_desc":""},{"cat_id":"3","cat_name":"INDIAN","cat_desc":""},{"cat_id":"4","cat_name":"abc","cat_desc":""},{"cat_id":"5","cat_name":"def","cat_desc":""},{"cat_id":"6","cat_name":"hi","cat_desc":""}]
      ''';
      http.Response response = http.Response(jsonString, 200);
      print('getCategory Response: ${response.body}');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return itemCategoryFromJson(response.body);
      } else {
        return List<ItemCategory>();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return List<ItemCategory>(); // return an empty list on exception/error
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = getCategory();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ItemCategory>> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(
                              elevation: 6.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 6.0,
                                    bottom: 6.0,
                                    left: 8.0,
                                    right: 8.0),
                                child: Row(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      snapshot.data[index].catId,
                                    ),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Text(
                                      snapshot.data[index].catName,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ));
                        });
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```